# CP2109 interface to controller

Tags: microcontroller, usb, uart

I want to implement USB to UART bridge in my application. I am planning to use [CP2109](https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/CP2102-9.pdf) IC.

Schematic is as shown:

[image: Schematic]

My doubt is RST, Suspend, ~Suspend, RI,DCD,DTR,DSR,CTS,RTS,TXD and RXD are controller signals or MAX232 signals ( PC side )?

Please someone advise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Page 1 on the datasheet "Note: For newer designs, the CP2102N devices offer compatible footprints and are recommended for use instead of the
CP2102/9."

Answer (score 1):

Datasheet chapter 3 allows only -0.3 to 5.8 V on those pins, this means UART (TTL) and not RS232 signal levels, because the latter uses much higher (and negative) voltages.

Comment: Thanks Turbo for your answer, Can I use only TXD, RXD, RTS and CTS pins of IC? ( TXD,RXD - UART2 of LPC1769 and CTS,RTS - GPIO pins)